# Restoring data from a large partition

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I have a dedicated server. I've been developing an app to handle my music collection, and I had in the past set up a backup solution for my code, but I blacklisted the /music folder . And the worst has happened, I've accidentally recursively deleted the folder using unlink and rmdir php's function. There was about 50GB of data, .mp3, .ogg and .m4a .

I know there is solutions around, like foremost, scalpel , photorec, extundelete to recover deleted data.

Mostly, my problem is that the partition where data stood /dev/sda2 is 897Gb, and the system partition is only 20Gb. I asked my system provider OVH if I can add some more space via another DD or USB drive, but it's impossible. I also asked if I can pay for a copy of the entire disk, but it's also not possible.

---

**I'm thinking about three possible solutions:**

- Use one of the program and copy to the available space in /, and do it several times, each time I'll scp the current recovered data to another server I own.
- Other solution would be to make an image of the partition and scp it progressively to the second server ( I really don't know if it's possible )
- Third solution, would be to repartition the /home sda2 main partition, but 
  I'm afraid this will corrupt / erase / overwrite the not yet recovered data.

What can I do to recover my data in this special case?

Answer (score 2):

> Use one of the program and copy to the available space in /, and do it several 
>   times, each time i 'll scp the current recovered data to another server i owe.

This might work. Though it is going to take some time.

> Other solution would be to make an image of the partition and scp it progressively to the second server ( I really don't know if it's possible )

It will create a file on the server 1st so you would need the space there 1st...  so no... Example of this

```
dd if=/dev/{partition} ibs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror | 
(ssh {IP} dd of=/partition.img obs=4096)
```

> Third solution, would be to repartition the /home sda2 main partition, but i'm afraid this will corrupt / erase / overwriting the data

It will.

---

Alternative:

Can you use `sshfs`? That would save your life if you can: mount the disk on your desktop, and you can use `ddrescue` to make an image.

Comment: The alternative solution is a *fantastic* idea...  +1 *I would use `ddrescue` instead of `dd` tough*...

Comment: You're solution looks amazing  @Rinzwind ! i didn't know the existence of sshfs, thank you very much. I m going to try it tomorrow.

Comment: I'm trying your solution @Rinzwind, but i get : `root@123.123.123.123:/dev/sda2: Not a directory`, I'm a bit lost, how can i make a disk image if i can't mount the device ? Should i mount / ? Thanks again

Comment: I've just mount /, it works ... I'm in awe !

Comment: @rubberscotch cool :D Now make a backup (dd or ddrescue) of it  and try to get all your stuff back. Extract your files  from the backup, not the original disk.

Comment: @Rinzwind, thanks for all your explaination, but now i'm stuck trying to make the backup : i've done on my local box `mkdir /mnt/distant` then `sudo sshfs -p 1234 root@123.123.123:/ /mnt/distant/`, it works , it's mounted i can see all the folders. But ...   when i `dd if=/mnt/distant/ of=image.img bs=32M`, i'm getting `dd: reading error <</mnt/distant/>>: is a directory` ... I continue googling .... thank you again ^^

Comment: @Rinzwind, today i figured out a solution, i've inverted the logic : so i've been using sshfs on the box where the device i want to image is, i've mounted on it the 2To partition of the second box i owe, and i dd the /dev/sda2 to the newly mounted space ... And it works :) I just have to wait  now .Thanks again .